# How good are clay bar substitutes for "claying"?

Tags: detailing, polishing

I was checking out various different clay bars and ran across this [Nanoskin product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CUAWJ6G) with quite allot of good reviews which is supposed to be an easier substitute:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone here had encountered this product and if it's really a good substitute for claying in the "clay, polish, wax" process for the average person who is not taking their car to a show and just wants it to look decent.

**Postscript**

I found this [Auto Fetish Detail](https://www.youtube.com/user/autofetishdetail) guy on youtube has some good info both [on claying](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zo_xPjsEZwg) and these [nanoskin type products](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhDBb6L-xRg).

Comment: I'm afraid this might be a question seeking for opinions and thus off-topic for SE. What are your criteria for something being a good substitute? What results are acceptable for you?

Comment: @JoErNanO Exactly what the phrase "good substitute" implies, namely that it does the same job with a similar result, with equivalent or less work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used both clay bar and clay mitt (similar to the product you've posted).

Advantages of clay mitt:

- if dropped, you can clean it off and use it rather than throw it away
- typically covers larger surface area in a single pass, allowing for quicker claying of the whole car

Advantages of clay bar:

- you can continue to fold and expose new surface to maintain efficiency
- you can get get different strengths to tackle different levels of contamination

Both need oodles of surface lubrication (clay lube or soapy water) to prevent marring the paint surface.

Both will eventually need to be replaced after they pick up sufficient contamination.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're saying, the product I'm referring to is not a clay mitt.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes they are essentially the same technology. Here is a product page: https://www.amazon.com/Auto-Chem-Professional-CLAY-MITT-Detailing-Clay/dp/B00UI3U98C

Comment: The nanoskin product also comes in different strengths, they sell both a "fine" and a "medium" one.  I get the impression from some research I've done that it's pretty much a perfect substitute, except if you are detailing outside and the surface temperature of the car is excessively high, like above 140*F, then your only option is clay.